# Case Sensitive include when builing using ndk-build

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, shared-libraries, android.mk

I am getting a strange problem. I want to build native code of android app which is in C++. I have included some includes in Android.mk. One of the include is like this

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/borders
```

Now I have a header file pqr/abc.h in borders which is included by a file xyz.h like this

```
#include "PQR/abc.h"
```

I am getting error that PQR/ABC.h does not exist.When I change PQR to pqr it works. But this problem occurs on my machine only. I am on mac and ndk version r9d. How to resolve case sensitive includes?

Answer (score 0):

This is how case insensitive paths work on Windows filesystem. There is little you can do about it but carefully fix all relevant `#include` statements in your sources. Other people with Linux or Mac will thank you for this effort.

On the other hand, the problem is in the file system, not the machine. So, if you have a Windows share somewhere (maybe even a Windows partition on your local machine), you can put the source files there, and most likely your build will pass.